# How can I change the current URL?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that changes the pages from within JavaScript:

```
var newUrl = [some code to build up URL string];
window.location.replace(newUrl);
```

But it doesn't change the top URL, so when someone clicks the back button it doesn't go back to the previous page.

How can I have JavaScript change the top URL as well so the browser back button works.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

```
document.location.href = newUrl;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location

Answer (score 62):

Simple assigning to `window.location` or `window.location.href` should be fine:

```
window.location = newUrl;
```

However, your new URL will cause the browser to load the new page, but it sounds like you'd like to modify the URL without leaving the current page.  You have two options for this:

1. Use the URL hash.  For example, you can go from `example.com` to `example.com#foo` without loading a new page.  You can simply set `window.location.hash` to make this easy.  Then, you should listen to the HTML5 `hashchange` event, which will be fired when the user presses the back button.  This is not supported in older versions of IE, but check out [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), which makes this work in all browsers.
2. You could use HTML5 History to modify the path without reloading the page.  This will allow you to change from `example.com/foo` to `example.com/bar`.  Using this is easy:

   `window.history.pushState("example.com/foo");`

   When the user presses "back", you'll receive the window's `popstate` event, which you can easily listen to (jQuery):

   `$(window).bind("popstate", function(e) { alert("location changed"); });`

   Unfortunately, this is only supported in very modern browsers, like Chrome, Safari, and the Firefox 4 beta.

Comment: *the .replace method on strings will not change the string it was applied to, it will generate a new string."* - the `window.location.replace()` method isn't the same as the `String.prototype.replace()` method because `window.location` isn't a string (it's an object).  `window.location.replace()` replaces the current URL with a new one, whilst overwriting the old URL's entry in the history.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Looking back, this is by far the best answer. document.location.href has nothing on pushState

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to update the relative path you can also do

`window.location.pathname = '/relative-link'`

`"http://domain.com" -> "http://domain.com/relative-link"`

Answer (score 10):

Hmm, I would use

```
window.location = 'http://localhost/index.html#?options=go_here';
```

I'm not exactly sure if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 9):

This will do it:

```
window.history.pushState(null,null,'https://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script> 
    var url= "http://www.google.com"; 
    window.location = url; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to redirect the user to another URL is by using `window.location.assign` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Nevertheless, if what you want is to change the URL of the page without redirecting the user, then you may use the `window.history.replaceState` function (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState). A combination of this and `window.history.pushState` is what Single Page Applications (SPAs) use nowadays to keep track of the user navigating throughout the application so that the back button works as expected

You can take a look at the examples in the documentation links I provided to give you an idea on the usage of these functions