# Try to redirect a page with javascript but the browser downloads the page

Tags: javascript, html

Try to redirect a page with javascript:

```
window.location.href = "/someFolder/page.aspx"
```

but the browser downloads the page instead of entering.

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. Can you redirect to other pages? If so then it's not a problem with the JavaScript - if I had to guess it would be that the server is serving the file with the incorrect file type.

Comment: Did you try to just update the location manually to see if the page is diplayed or downloaded (second choice i think)

Comment: @James didn't try to redirect to other pages. It must be this aspx. In some cases the browser redirects. In other cases it tries to download the aspx page

Comment: @Arthur manually it works

Comment: there's a number of questions related to this - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846935/how-to-change-page-from-within-javascript
As James said above, this looks like a problem with how the page is being served from the server.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing the exact same URL manually and with the JS ?
A good test is to use your JS to be redirected, cancel the download, copy this URL, and test on a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page that redirects was .html. Changing it to .aspx resolved the problem, now it just redirects, it's not trying to download it.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to open the page
Use window.open("www.google.com")
Explain what exactly you are looking at