# OnClientClick does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have 2 identical buttons same proprieties, with the difference that 1 is asp button and another one is HTML button, I am trying to redirect to another page, and HTML button works fine, but asp button does not redirect for some reason. I already recreated asp button to see if it is visual studio bug, but it is not. I don't need to use asp controls, but just want to know what i am doing wrong. here is my code example:

HTML Button

```
<button type="button" id="Btn_16" 
        class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger butao" onclick="see_16()">16 </button>
```

asp Button

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_16" runat="server" Text="16"
      CssClass="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger butao" OnClientClick="see_16()" />
```

DIV like a button (Also works)

```
<div id="Btn_16" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger butao" onclick="see_16()">16</div>
```

All the controls have the same name, but in my code they are commented, so that is not the problem.

see_16 javascript function :

```
function see_16() {
{
    window.location.href("16.aspx");
};}
```

Comment: See [how to change pages with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846935/how-to-change-page-from-within-javascript).

Comment: @mason -> do try the solution first before commenting on it. OnClientClick="see_16();return false;" worked .. same way as the OnClientClick="return SomeMethod();".

Comment: @Sailor He is not changing the page location correctly.

Comment: @mason See the below answer and comments. Solution worked for user which is great.

Comment: @Sailor `window.location.href("16.aspx");` is not valid syntax in Google Chrome. Perhaps it works in other browsers, but not Chrome. Depending on the client, it would be quite a big bug if your code doesn't work for the browser that holds 60% of the market share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server-side ASP.NET Button always calls the `postback` event. So you need to disable the `postback`. This works as you want:

```
OnClientClick="see_16();return false;"
```

And of course as @ajai Jothi also said you JS should be like this:

```
window.location.href = "16.aspx";
```

Answer (score -1):

`'window.location.href'` is not a function

```
function see_16() {
   window.location.href = "16.aspx";
}
```

Comment: This is only part of the answer, and does not address the postback issue.

Comment: Also you can do a great deal to improve the quality of this answer by explaining things in more detail than, essentially, a code-only answer.

Answer (score -1):

`OnClientClick=SomeMethod()` event of that BUTTON, it return by default `true` so after that function it do postback.

for solution use:

```
//use this code in BUTTON  ==>   OnClientClick="return SomeMethod();"

//and your function like this

<script type="text/javascript">
  function SomeMethod(){
    // put your code here 
    return false;
  }
</script>
```