# JS don't opening link if else

Tags: javascript, html

Alerts are working in both conditions but I can't make a transfer to my HTML link if the password is correct
I ALSO TRIED - document.location.href / window.location.href / document.location.replace

```
document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function () {

    var pass = document.querySelector('#pass').value;
    var passrepeat = document.querySelector('#passrepeat').value;
    if (pass === passrepeat) {
        //alert("GJ")
        local.href = "SuccessfulLogin.html" 
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong pass")
    }
}
```

Comment: SHould be an error in your console with `local`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the current URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846935/how-can-i-change-the-current-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct is `window.location.href`

and also use `event.preventDefault()` in submit function.

```
document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
 ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't works  `window.location.href = "SuccessfulLogin.html"`
But if I write `alert("Correct password")` it works

Comment: HTML file is also added to the folder

Comment: Does `url` changed?

Comment: I have three files in my folder :
PassMatch.html / 
PassMatch.js / 
SuccessfulLogin.html / 
as u see, I tried to make a simple function to transfer to my link if pass correct

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.replace("SuccessfulLogin.html");
window.open("SuccessfulLogin.html", "_self");
```

```
window.open("SuccessfulLogin.html")
```

Would usually open in a new tab but the "_self" parameter makes it open in the same tab.

Comment: also don't work, but in this condition, it can show an alert("GJ")

Comment: @NeedSumHelp I changed my answer.