# I'm trying to use a Javascript function to change to another htm

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to click on an image, which will call a javascript function. The function is intended to change from one page to another web page on the same site. I don't want to open() a new page, but an existing page within the current site.
I tried using an anchor tag, with the href targetting the url of the destination. But I dont want an anchor, I want to use a clickable image.
I also tried the window.open() method but ended up with lots of opened windows!
I then tried donuts "window.location.replace(newUrl);" which worked instantly. How do I vote-up donuts advice from pure time ago? Can't see no up-arrow to the left of the post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the current URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846935/how-can-i-change-the-current-url)

Comment: Doesn't this also essentially answer the question? `<a><img /></a>` Just put the image or button inside the anchor tags.

Comment: @talfreds pretty much with exception that `img` in an empty tag and has no closing tag...

Comment: I'll edit it  both work though

Comment: `open()` accepts other parameters next to the URL. `_blank` is the default behaviour. You can however change it: 

`window.open('https://duckduckgo.com','_parent')`

More details here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Donut I'm not suprised your rep is so high. Your line "window.location.replace(newUrl);" worked instantly. Thankyou. Timo yours did not, I just ended up with many open windows that I did not want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript to make a button or image into a link.

For an image, as others have pointed out in the comments, just do

```
<a href="..."> <img src="..."> </a>
```

For a button, see [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link).

Comment: I apologise for not being clearer! I have no intention of using any forms in my program, so the above link does not help.

Comment: @SimonOsaka The second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906611/1798629) to that question shows you how to do it with just a `<button>`. Did this answer your question?